# Login and register in just one page using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm working on a project. (web)

The first version, has a separate login.php and register.php which login calls a .js to do an ajax validation. the same happends with register.

The second version, the page have a login and register form in just one page like this:

[Login and register in one page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Ctp.png)

The problem is in this new page version, I import (

(for better understanding, In the image enclosed yellow)

My first idea was put a code to ejecute every .js separate(one .js for login and one .js for register).
like this:

```
if( $_POST['submit_login'] ) {
 echo "<script src='js/login.js'></script>";
}
else if( $_POST['submit_register'] ) {
 echo "<script src='js/register.js'></script>";
}
```

but the code above does: the first click import the .js, then at the second click to log in/register, load correctly.

The optimal idea is to load every .js where appropriate. The .js at just one click like all sites.

***The code for login.js is:***

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        var datos = $("form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "loginCode.php?type=pdo",
            data: datos,
            success: function(data) {
                switch($.trim(data)) {
                    case "success":
                            notification("success", "Usuario válido");
                         $(location).attr('href','index.php');
                        break;
                    case "failed":
                            notification("failed", "Usuario no válido");
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            }
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
function notification(type, text) {
    $notify = $("<div class='notification " + type + "'></div>").appendTo("#notification_wrapper");
    $notify.append("<div class='errorImage'></div><div class='info'>" + text + "</div>");
    $notify.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut('fast');
}
```

***And the code for register.js:***

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        var datos = $("form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "signupCode.php?type=pdo",
            data: datos,
            success: function(data) {
                switch($.trim(data)) {
                    case "success1":
                            notification("success", "Registro completado");
                        break;
                    case "failed1":
                            notification("failed", "Ha ocurrido un error");
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            }
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
function notification(type, text) {
    $notify = $("<div class='notification " + type + "'></div>").appendTo("#notification_wrapper");
    $notify.append("<div class='errorImage'></div><div class='info'>" + text + "</div>");
    $notify.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut('fast');
}
```

***The html form login is quite normal like this:***

```
<form id="form_1" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_login" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="form_2" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_register" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Hope u can help me, I was trying to do that 1 week ago but this wins me.
Sorry if my english is not so good.
Thanks u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add one one js

```
$(document).on('submit','#form_1',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $('#form_1');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'loginCode.php?type=pdo',
        data:frm.serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            switch($.trim(data)) {
                case "success":
                        notification("success", "Usuario válido");
                     $(location).attr('href','index.php');
                    break;
                case "failed":
                        notification("failed", "Usuario no válido");
                    break;
                default:
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
})
$(document).on('submit','#form_2',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $('#form_2');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'signupCode.php?type=pdo',
        data:frm.serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            switch($.trim(data)) {
                case "success1":
                        notification("success", "Registro completado");
                    break;
                case "failed1":
                        notification("failed", "Ha ocurrido un error");
                    break;
                default:
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
})
function notification(type, text) {
    $notify = $("<div class='notification " + type + "'></div>").appendTo("#notification_wrapper");
    $notify.append("<div class='errorImage'></div><div class='info'>" + text + "</div>");
    $notify.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut('fast');
}
```

Comment: thanks! that whas very nice! I need to learn more ajax or js haha, thank you very much!!! u're the best dude.